# Are there any tools or best practices for documenting an ElasticSearch db

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for documentation about documenting an ElasticSearch deployment (you can see why this is challenging to Google!).

My question is really two questions.  Are there best practices for documenting an ElasticSearch installation?  -and- Are there any tools that aid in the visualization of an ElasticSearch installation.  I guess it would be akin to a sql db schema (ER diagram or whatever).  I've scoured Google without much luck and I didn't find anything on SO.

Documenting ES may be a bit more challenging than documenting a sql db since you probably want to be able to show the relationship between end user queries and indexing to explain the context of each mapping.  Furthermore, it would be useful to visualize the cluster (perhaps a separate problem that could be solved with existing tools).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: elasticsearch head http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/ does a nice job of showing your cluster it presents a matrix of nodes by indices with shards (primary and replication) slotted into there spots.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Its certainly a useful tool but I'm looking more for a way to design a search application before I build it.  This way I can reason through the implementation and communicate ideas to other people involved both present and future.